# Prolog, filter duplicates, while keeping list order

Tags: prolog

I am trying to make a rule called `supressEcho(A, B)`, `A` is list with duplicates and `B` is list w/o. Using sort, removes duplicates, but it also sorts them in alpha order. What Ι have so far :

```
supressEchos([],[]) :-!.  
supressEchos(A,B) :- supressHelp(A, [], B). 

supressHelp([], A, A) :- !.  
supressHelp([A | Tail],List, B) :-  
    member(A,List),  
    supressHelp(Tail, List, B),!.  
supressHelp([A | Tail],List, B) :-  
    supressHelp(Tail,[A|List], B), !.
```

This returns list with out duplicates, but in reverse order as Ι add new non duplicate to the front. How do Ι go about adding to end of my list or should Ι make a `reverse(A,B)` to help?

```
supressEcho([a,a,a,b,b,c],X)
```

returns `X = [c,b,a].`

Answer (score 1):

there is a (deprecated) predicate [delete](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=delete/3)/3 that could help:

```
supressEchos([],[]).
supressEchos([A|Tail],[A|B]) :-
    delete(Tail,A,R),
    supressEchos(R,B).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%%The answer to my issue was to implement reverse(A,B).  
reverse([],A,A) :- !.  
reverse([A|Tail],B, C) :- reverse(Tail, [A|B], C).  
supressEchos([],[]) :-!.  
supressEchos(A,B) :- supressHelp(A, [], B).  

supressHelp([], A, B) :- reverse(A,B).  
supressHelp([A | Tail],List, B) :-  
member(A,List),
supressHelp(Tail, List, B),!.
supressHelp([A | Tail],List, B) :-
supressHelp(Tail,[A|List], B), !.
```

There is defiantly a better way to implement this, but if anyone needs a quick fix, here ya go.